# Making margin relative to resolution

Tags: html, css

Effectively I want my margin's to change based upon the resolution,

On my 1920x1080 computer, everything fits fine. On my tablet with a smaller resolution it overlaps/makes everything look weird.

Ideally I want to have the text either cut off, or change to fit better..

Currently just using

```
margin-left: 375px;
margin-right: 375px;
```

on certain elements I want this to be the case for, (which is all of them, beside backgrounds etc).

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to take a look to media queries. they allow you to define rules depending on the viewport width, height and rotation (portrait-landscape).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
#myDiv {
    margin-left: 375px;
    margin-right: 375px;
}

@media (max-width: 1900px) {
    #myDiv {
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: 150px;
    }
}
```